# Match a 2-digit with separated comma (float digits not included)

Tags: python, regex

For each string input I need to match only a 2-digit (or many) (that need to be separated by space or by comma+space (not comma+digit).

In the case below you see the result of some examples. I don't want my regex to catch the 2 first examples.

```
def cleanse_no(string):
    regex = r"(?:^|\s)(\d{2})\b"
    string = str(string).strip(" .,€")
    list_digits = re.findall(regex, string)
    digits = ", ".join(list_digits)
    return digits

test_digits = ["€ 22.22", ". 23,600.90", "25 45 61", "22, 232, 36, 02,", "1, 23, 456"]
for test_dgt in test_digits:
    print(test_dgt,"-------find_no--------->",cleanse_no(test_dgt))
```

I get these results:

> ```
> € 22.22 -------find_no---------> 22
> . 23,600.90 -------find_no---------> 23
> 25 45 61 -------find_no---------> 25, 45, 61
> 22, 232, 36, 02, -------find_no---------> 22, 36, 02
> 1, 23, 456 -------find_no---------> 23
> ```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
def cleanse_no(s):
    regex = r"(?<!\S)\d{2}(?=,?(?:\s|$))"
    return ", ".join(re.findall(regex, s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8xVHut) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KrnGH/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace left boundary
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?=,?(?:\s|$))` - immediately to the right of the current position, there must be an optional comma followed with either a whitespace or end of string.

Comment: Last part can also be written as `(?=,?(?!\S))` and should be the quicker version.

Comment: I know, I just did not want to use that due to its readability.